# How to Pass an Int from non-activity class to Activity class

Tags: java, android

Android is similar to Java in terms of convention but why does my setter and getter methods won't work.

I have a spinner(which is a non-activity class) with code like this:

```
int finalposition;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) {
            if (i==pos){
                 setPosition(pos);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setPosition(int position){
        finalposition= position;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return finalposition;
    }
```

and in onCreate(), here is my MainActivity(which extends Activity):

```
//spinner
spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener2());

//button
gPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getPath);
        gPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CustomOnItemSelectedListener2 coisl2= new CustomOnItemSelectedListener2();
                if(coisl2.getPosition()==1)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position:"+coisl2.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

What I need to do is that if I select the item at position `1` in my spinner and clicked `gPath` button, a toast saying "It Works!" should be displayed. However, it does not work. I put a toast(displaying the position that was taken from calling getPosition()) on the button. When I selected the item at position `1` and click the button, it returned `position:0`. So that's why it won't enter the if-condition that I implemented and I'm wondering why. I do this in `Java` but why am I having troubles in `Android`. What is wrong/missing in my code?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can't you use `spinner2.getSelectedItem()` in the `View.OnClickListener.onClick()` method?

Comment: What exactly is your loop doing in the spinner class? Wont just setPosition(pos) suffice ? and when you say when item at 1 is selected, you mean the second item in the list I guess, right ? coz' of it's the first, then you need to know that pos starts from 0

Comment: And what is the code in CustomOnItemSelectedListener2 ? How would it know which item in the spinner is selected, if u just created a new object and immediately called its getPosition method?

Comment: @AlexWalterbos Yes I can. But I want to know if I can pass values like the above. I would need it for others not only on spinners.

Comment: @AnudeepBulla the first code is implemented under ` CustomOnItemSelectedListener2`. When I put toasts in there, it displays the positions(ex: I click 1st item, it displays 0, I click 2nd item, it displays 1). But when I pass it, it displays 0 in all items

Comment: That's because you're creating a new `Listener` in the `onClick` method, you should use the instance you pass to the `spinner2` in `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Wow, that was a little mistake that I barely saw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You are creating a new instance of the listener on each onClick, and that listener would obviously not know which item was selected in the spinner, since it isn't effectively listening over anything.

```
//declare this as a class object
CustomOnItemSelectedListener2 coisl2= new CustomOnItemSelectedListener2();

//This follows in your onCreate
//spinner
spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(coisl2);

//button
gPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getPath);
        gPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(coisl2.getPosition()==1)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position:"+coisl2.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this:

Under MainActivity.java

```
    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            coisl2= new CustomOnItemSelectedListener2(MainActivity.this,spinner2);

            //button
            gPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getPath);
            gPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    if(coisl2.getPosition()==1)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It Works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position:"+coisl2.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Under CustomOnItemSelectedListener2.java( You can create this class like below)

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener2 
{
    int finalposition;
    public CustomOnItemSelectedListener2(Context context,Spinner spinner)
    {
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setPosition(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    public void setPosition(int position){
        finalposition= position;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return finalposition;
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you want...